"Return" at the end of my function doesn't seem to be working
I have a function which is meant to simulate the trajectory of a frisbee, with basic considerations of lift and drag. The forces on the frisbee are lift, drag and gravity. It has a predetermined launch angle, "theta_0" (angle determining the angle of the velocity) and and angle which describes the angle of the frisbee relative to the horizontal "beta". It then uses a for loop to calculate the position, acceleration and velocity at every timestep. It compiles these in their own individual lists. If the frisbee reaches the gorund (y[-1]<0), it stops the simulation. At the end, I want to return the lists for x and y position, simply titled x and y respectively. However, this does not seem to be working. I have omitted some variables which are defined earlier on in my code to keep the post a bit lighter. Every variable seen in the function should be accounted for.
def trajectory(x_0,y_0,theta_0,v_0, r):

  vx_0 = v_0*(math.cos(theta_0))
  vy_0 = v_0*(math.sin(theta_0))
  A = (math.pi*r**2)

  ax_0 = 0
  ay_0 = -1*g

  t = [0]
  x = [x_0]
  y = [y_0]
  vx = [vx_0]
  vy = [vy_0]
  ax = [ax_0]
  ay = [ay_0]


  for i in range(STEPS):

    theta = math.atan(vy[i]/vx[i])
    alpha = beta_0 - theta

    CD = (0.085 + 3.30*(alpha - (-0.052))**2)
    CL = (0.13 + 3.09*alpha)

    t.append(t[i]+DT)

    x.append(x[i]+vx[i]*DT)
    y.append(y[i]+vy[i]*DT)
    vx.append(vx[i]+ax[i]*DT)
    vy.append(vy[i]+ay[i]*DT)

    drag = float(((-1/2)*RHO*A*CD*alpha*vx[i]**2))
    drag_x = float((drag*math.cos(theta)))
    drag_y = float((drag*math.sin(theta)))

    lift = float(((-1/2)*RHO*A*CL*alpha*vx[i]**2))
    lift_x = float((lift*math.cos(theta)))
    lift_y = float((lift*math.sin(theta)))

    ax.append((1/m)*(-1*lift_x - drag_x))
    ay.append((1/m)*(-m*g + lift_y - drag_y))

    if y[-1]<0:
      del(y[-1])
      del(x[-1])
      del(vx[-1])
      del(vy[-1])
      del(ax[-1])
      del(ay[-1])
      break


  return x,y

trajectory(x_0,y_0,theta_0,v_0,r)
print (x)

The code above returns the error " 'x' is not defined" when it attempts to print. If I put print statements  for 'x' and 'y' inside the function, they print, but I want to plot my results so I need the fucntion to return the lists for me. I know the code has other problems, but I'm not worried about those right now, I just want to know what is causing this error. Thanks!

I add you to the illustrious chain. Next time I recommend pasting your title into google. You actually have a really good title.

You are not assigning anything to your function call.
Try:
x,y = trajectory(x_0,y_0,theta_0,v_0,r)
print (x)

